# Explanation of a a differential of a tensor with respect to its FFT.

Tags: derivatives, tensor-products

I found in a paper that, for a tensor $\mathcal{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times n_2 \times n_3}$
$$\nabla || \mathcal{X}||= \frac{\partial ||\mathcal{X} ||}{\partial \overline{\mathcal{X}}} \times_3 F^{*}_{n_3}$$
Where $\overline{\mathcal{X}}=\mathcal{X} \times_3 F_{n_3}$ is the DFT of $\mathcal{X}$ along the third dimension.
The product is called n-mod product.

They said that they used the chain rule, But I can't write it right.

I dont't know if it helps, but the norm depends on the $\overline{\mathcal{X}}$.

Comment: I cannot follow the notation you are using. Do you have a link to the original paper?

Comment: Yes, the paper is Tensor Robust Principal Component Analysis viaNon-Convex Low Rank Approximation.